# jQuery find all elements containing specific data attribute and convert to an array

Tags: jquery, each

How can I extract all elements on the page having certain data attribute, and convert the results into dropdown list.

This is what I got so far:

```
<div data-position="first" data-section="Main Section"></div>
<div data-position="second" data-section="Sub Section"></div>
<div data-position="third" data-section="Footer Section"></div>

result = '';
result2 = '';
$('#content').each(function(){
    result += $(this).find('div[data-position]').data('position');
    result2 += $(this).find('div[data-section]').data('section');
})
```

The idea is to have something like:

```
<option value="first">Main Section</option>
<option value="second">Sub Section</option>
<option value="third">Footer Section</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String append approach

```
$('div[data-position][data-section]').each(function(){
    var data = $(this).data(),
        option = '<option value="' + data.position + '">' + data.section + '</option>';
    $('#selectID').append(option);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#content div[data-position][data-section]").each(function() {
    var position = $(this).data('position');
    var section = $(this).data('section');
    $("#selectID").append($("<option>", {
        value: position,
        text: section
    });
});
```